# How to build a simple application, that uses audio filter (eg. damping of sound level with distance)

Tags: audio, filter, signal-processing

I would like to build a really simple app.

Let say, that apps GUI consists of 2 buttons: "5 meters" and "15 meters".
When the first button is clicked, an audio file would play. When the second button is clicked, the app would apply a filter to the same audio file, so that the user will be able to hear how that same sound sounds like 10 meters away.

Firstly I would like to know, in which programming language an application like this could be written. I have some experience in Java and C++.

Secondly, I would like to know, how to build audio filters (e.g. damping of sound level with distance) and how to integrate it into the app.

I really dont know, where to start.. Any practical example or similar application with available source code would be of much help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would be the platform for your app? iOS, android, linux, windows ...? Anyway, I recomend you to have a look at SFML. It's a library in C++ that could help you for multimedia task

[about audio in SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/audio-spatialization.php)

there is an example for audio levels that change with distance.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! SMFL looks very handy, but since the goal of my project is to learn, how to build filters from scratch, it's not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The sound pressure decreases by 1/r. So a doubling of the distance results in a 6 dB lower amplitude. This should be easy to model by a distance dependent amplification.

The interesting part of the problem is the sound absorption caused by air. This absorption is frequency dependent (it is higher for high frequencies) and also depends or air pressure, humidity and temperature. You can find a detailed quantitative model in the ISO 9613-1 standard.